# How to repeat code after you finish an action on node.js

Tags: node.js, loops, puppeteer

I want to ask the user what player they want to look up after they finish looking up a previous player, so they can continuously look up players. Right now it just ends after I look up 1 player.

```
console.clear();

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

console.log(`
_______  _______  _______  ___            _______  __   __  _______ 
|       ||       ||   _   ||   |          |       ||  |_|  ||       |
|       ||   _   ||  |_|  ||   |          |    ___||       ||    ___|
|       ||  | |  ||       ||   |          |   |___ |       ||   |___ 
|      _||  |_|  ||       ||   |___  ___  |    ___| |     | |    ___|
|     |_ |       ||   _   ||       ||   | |   |___ |   _   ||   |___ 
|_______||_______||__| |__||_______||___| |_______||__| |__||_______|
                                     
`);


const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({ sigint: true });
const name = prompt("Player: ");


scrapeProduct('https://bwstats.shivam.pro/user/' + name);

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
   
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el2] = await page.$x('/html/body/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]');
    const txt2 = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
    const lvl = await txt2.jsonValue();

    const [el] = await page.$x('/html/body/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/p[3]');
    const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');
    const fkdr = await txt.jsonValue();

    const [el1] = await page.$x('/html/body/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/p[4]');
    const txt1 = await el1.getProperty('textContent');
    const BBLR = await txt1.jsonValue();

    const [el3] = await page.$x('/html/body/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]');
    const txt3 = await el3.getProperty('textContent');
    const wlr = await txt3.jsonValue();


    console.log(lvl);
    console.log(fkdr);
    console.log(BBLR);
    console.log("Win/Loss Ratio (WLR): " + wlr);
    console.log("---------------------------------------------");

}
```

I tried moving the code under the brackets above and inside the brackets and adding a while loop but it would just continuously ask me for a player.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop, but you need to `await` for each request.

You could do something like this:

```
async function doit() {
  while (true) {
    const name = prompt('Player: ');

    try {
      await scrapeProduct('https://bwstats.shivam.pro/user/' + name);
    } catch {
      console.log('something went wrong');
    }
  }
}

doit();
```

The loop has to be inside an `async` function because you can only use `await` inside an `async` function or on the top level of modules (so if the loop is at the top level and `await` is inside the loop it won't work).

Then it will work like this:

```
_______  _______  _______  ___            _______  __   __  _______ 
|       ||       ||   _   ||   |          |       ||  |_|  ||       |
|       ||   _   ||  |_|  ||   |          |    ___||       ||    ___|
|       ||  | |  ||       ||   |          |   |___ |       ||   |___ 
|      _||  |_|  ||       ||   |___  ___  |    ___| |     | |    ___|
|     |_ |       ||   _   ||       ||   | |   |___ |   _   ||   |___ 
|_______||_______||__| |__||_______||___| |_______||__| |__||_______|
                                     

Player: joe
something went wrong
Player: jim
Level: 8 ✫
Final Kills/Deaths Ratio (FKDR): 1.38
Beds Broken/Lost Ratio (BBLR): 0.3
Win/Loss Ratio (WLR): 0.51
---------------------------------------------
Player: ^C
```

Comment: bro i love you so much

Comment: If you want to end this endless loop after the user find their player, just add a "break;" statement within the loop.